# GNOME Main Menu; remove arrow

Tags: menu

Is there any way to *easily* remove the dropdown arrow when using the GNOME menu in Ubuntu 10.10 or 11.04? I don't want to need to recompile the panel or anything messy unless I need to.

Just to clarify, it's one of the two GNOME menus available by default on Ubuntu. The arrow looks gross :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9126937#post9126937) on ubuntuforums dedicated to resolving this.  Below I've just summarised the thread - note - apparently this 'fix' depends on the theme you are using.  Looking through the thread from back-to-front, there is an alternative suggested answer involving compiling code.  If below doesnt work for you have a look at the thread to see if the compile option works.

```
gedit ~/.gtkrc-2.0
```

replace the contents with the following (n.b. if there is a blank file you are probably not using a standard theme so this probably will not work)

```
style "panel-arrow-remove"
#the following removes the arrows from the panel
{
engine "pixmap"
    {
    image
    {
        function    = ARROW
        recolorable    = TRUE
        overlay_file    = "arrows/arrow-blank.png"
        overlay_border    = {2,2,2,2}
        overlay_stretch    = FALSE
        arrow_direction    = UP
    }
    image
    {
        function    = ARROW
        recolorable    = TRUE
        overlay_file    = "arrows/arrow-blank.png"
        overlay_border    = {2,2,2,2}
        overlay_stretch    = FALSE
        arrow_direction    = DOWN
    }
    image
    {
      function          = HANDLE
      recolorable       = TRUE
      overlay_file      = "arrows/arrow-blank.png"
      overlay_stretch   = FALSE
      orientation       = VERTICAL
    }
    image
    {
      function          = HANDLE
      overlay_file      = "arrows/arrow-blank.png"
      overlay_stretch   = FALSE
      orientation       = HORIZONTAL
    }
    }
}

widget_class "*PanelToplevel*"          style "panel-arrow-remove"
```

Save, reboot.

Comment: Worked perfectly. The file was blank, but even so it worked. I am using the default theme... nothing better than Ambiance ;)